# How can I recursively make a directory in the last directories using the command line?

Tags: command-line, directory, mkdir

Let's say that I have the following directory structure where the name of the directories does not matter:

```
currentDir/
   Dir1
      Dir1
         Dir1 *
      Dir2 *
      Dir3 *
   Dir2
      Dir1 *
      Dir2 
         Dir1*
   Dir3*
```

Is there a way that I can create a directory named "Texture" in only the directories at the end of the tree branch (in the example they are marked with an `*`). I would like to make it so that only those directories get a `Texture` directory but not any others.

All directories may or may not have files, but the end directories will not have any other directories in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First turn on recursive globbing

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Now we can look in all directories with `**`. To unset, you can use `shopt -u globstar` (it's off by default, so it will be off when you open a new shell).

In all of the below, remove `echo` after testing to actually create the directories.

If the end-of-tree directories are empty, you could test for emptiness and make the directory only if it is detected... something like

```
for d in **/; do [[ -z "$(ls -Aq "$d")" ]] && echo mkdir "$d"Texture; done
```

i.e. if the output of `ls -A (hidden files except current and parent dir) -q (printing ? for non-printing characters)` is empty, make a directory.

But since the directories contain files, we'd better test that there are no directories

```
for d in **/; do [[ -z "$(find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d)" ]] && echo mkdir "$d"Texture; done
```

`mindepth -1` is to stop the current directory being found... `find` sees hidden files, so we know those are included. Since any character should pass the test (we only want to check the output is empty), this should be fairly safe...

A more concise way [(sorry Greg)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (but actually all these methods do something similarly iffy - we can just about get away with using filenames as text since we aren't actually trying to do anything with those files themselves here):

```
for d in **/; do (ls -Alq "$d" | grep -q '^d') || echo mkdir "$d"Textures; done
```

here we add the `-l` flag for long output, which prints every file in the form

```
drwxrwxr-x 5 zanna zanna 4096 Sep 27 22:00 Dir1
```

we then *gulp* pipe that stuff into `grep` to see if any of the lines starts with `d` (meaning there's a directory). We don't want `grep` to print any of that meaningless unreliable text, so we just check its exit status with `-q` to see if it found anything. If it didn't, we make a directory (using the `||` or operator, meaning, do the next command if the last one failed). This should work, actually, even if your filenames contain horrible characters such as newlines, since `ls` prints them as `?` - every line *should* start with a letter indicating the file type, so, probably, no kittens will die.

Comment: You might want to restrict the for loop to iterate over directories: `for d in **/`; and don't forget to quote your variables

Comment: @glennjackman thanks a lot! It really breaks if not restricted to directories. And I thought I could quote the whole expression, but, nope!

Comment: The `$()` introduces a subshell, so the nested double quotes don't interact with each other at all.

Comment: Would it be possible to modify this to create the textures folder one level above the last folder so for in the example it would make currentDir/Dir1/Textures, currentDir/Dir1/Di1/Textures, currentDir/Dir2/, currentDir/Dir2/Dir2, and currentDir/

Comment: I don't understand your example - I think one level above the last should give `currentDir/Dir1/Dir1/Textures`, `currentDir/Dir1/Dir2/Textures` and `currentDir/Dir2/Textures` @kingcobra1986 also I couldn't figure out a way yet. Python can do it I assume...

Comment: So I guess another way to explain it is how do I get a directory inserted in the parent directories of the ones marked with an "*" so it would create a sibling instead of a child.

Comment: Wouldn't that produce http://paste.ubuntu.com/25629313/ @kingcobra1986 ?

Comment: Yes but it would also make a Texture directory that is a sibling to ./Dir3 as well. I don't know how to use that paste thing.  So the first level would be Dir1, Dir2, Dir3, and Texture

Comment: @kingcobra1986 for your sample I can use `for d in ./**/; do (ls -Alqd "$d"* 2>/dev/null | grep -q '^d') && echo mkdir "$d"Textures; done` - but this only checks that some child of the directory being considered contains a directory and then makes a sibling, so it will make siblings at every level where there is a child (every level but the last) regardless of the structure...

Answer (score 5):

Here's a painful `find -exec` call

Before:

```
$ tree currentDir
currentDir
├── Dir1
│   ├── Dir1
│   │   └── Dir1
│   ├── Dir2
│   └── Dir3
├── Dir2
│   ├── Dir1
│   └── Dir2
│       └── Dir1
└── Dir3
```

Create the Texture directories

```
$ find currentDir -depth -type d -exec bash -c 'cd "$1"; shopt -s globstar nullglob; texture=(**/Texture); [[ ${#texture[@]} -eq 0 ]] && mkdir Texture' _ '{}' \;
```

That relies on:

- find's `-depth` option to enable depth-first navigation
- bash's `globstar` shell option to enable recursive file pattern matching
- note the `_` argument: that goes into the bash var `$0` so that find's current pathname can be bash var `$1`

After

```
$ tree currentDir
currentDir
├── Dir1
│   ├── Dir1
│   │   └── Dir1
│   │       └── Texture
│   ├── Dir2
│   │   └── Texture
│   └── Dir3
│       └── Texture
├── Dir2
│   ├── Dir1
│   │   └── Texture
│   └── Dir2
│       └── Dir1
│           └── Texture
└── Dir3
    └── Texture
```

Comment: Outstanding use of `find` command, nice :-)

Comment: @glenn did you mean to VTC this as off topic? Seems fine to me, what am I missing? Also, why not `mkdir -p` instead of testing to see if it already exists?

Comment: Yes, this is not Ubuntu-specific. I think this is better off on SO. How would you use mkdir -p to only add the subdir at a leaf directory *without* testing?

Comment: Would it be possible to modify this to create the textures folder one level above the last folder so for in the example it would make currentDir/Dir1/Textures, currentDir/Dir1/Di1/Textures, currentDir/Dir2/, currentDir/Dir2/Dir2, and currentDir/

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
shopt -s globstar; for i in **/; do sub=$(find "$i" -type d | wc -l); if [[ "$sub" -eq 1 ]]; then mkdir "$i"/Texture; fi;done
```

Result:

```
currentDir
├── Dir1
│   ├── Dir1
│   │   └── Dir1
│   │       └── Texture
│   ├── Dir2
│   │   └── Texture
│   └── Dir3
│       └── Texture
├── Dir2
│   ├── Dir1
│   │   └── Texture
│   └── Dir2
│       └── Dir1
│           └── Texture
└── Dir3
    └── Texture
```

Comment: This only add a Texture file to currentDir/Dir3

Answer (score 1):

#### [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) makes this easy.

```bash
python3 -c 'import os
for d in [root for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".") if not any(dirs)]:
    os.mkdir(d + "/Texture")'
```

You can run that command from your shell. It passes a three-line script to [the Python 3 interpreter](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/python3.html), which runs it. The script builds a list of all the directories under `.` (the one you're in), then creates a `Texture` subdirectory in each one that did not already have any subdirectories.

This is simpler to write and easier to understand than most other methods, because Python has an [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) function that enumerates directories in a way that makes it easy to see which ones have subdirectories (and more generally because Python is a language many users find clean and intuitive).

**If you want to just *show* what new directories would be created instead of actually creating them, replace [`os.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) with [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).** Here's that, in case you want to copy and paste:

```bash
python3 -c 'import os
for d in [root for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".") if not any(dirs)]:
    print(d + "/Texture")'
```

There are ways to write either of these three-line commands on a single line, but there's no need. You can enter the command you want to use on an interactive shell prompt by typing or pasting it in, or you can use it in a shell script. When entered interactively, your shell will print `>` (unless you've set `$PS2` to  something different) at the beginning of the second and third lines. That's not a problem.

<sub>The foregoing assumes you're using a [Bourne-style shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Bourne_shell) like [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html), [`dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dash.1.html)/[*`sh`*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh), [`ksh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ksh93.1.html), [`zsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/zsh.1.html), [`posh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/posh.1.html), etc. ([Those](https://askubuntu.com/a/959702/22949) [three](https://askubuntu.com/a/959704/22949) [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/959698/22949) use `shopt -s globstar`. That command is Bash-specific, although [some other shells have a similar feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62665/11938). So if they work for you, this should too.) If you're using Ubuntu and you don't know what shell you're typing commands into, [it's `bash`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/292599/11938). If you're using [`csh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bsd-csh.1.html) or [`tcsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tcsh.1.html), you will have to place a `\` at the ends of the first two lines to avoid an `Unmatched '.` error, and you'll see `?` instead of `>`.</sub>

<sub>To test this method on an existing directory hierarchy without creating the directories, just use the second command as described above. But if you like, you can make a new directory hierarchy somewhere just for testing purposes. `mkdir -p dir/{a/{b/c,d,e},f/{g,h/i},j}` creates a directory tree with the same topology as the one in your example; `find dir -type d -exec touch {}/x \;` populates it with some files so you can check that the presence of non-directories isn't a problem; `cd dir` goes into it; and then you can test the commands shown above, as well as any other method you may be interested in, such as those presented in the other answers; then run [`tree`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tree.1.html).</sub>